# Terminal "do script" without echoing the command

Tags: applescript

I've got an inconsequential script written in applescript that calls terminal and using `do script` runs a command in terminal (in this case it's a call to curl and a later call to echo).  Is there any way to get terminal to run these commands without echoing the command itself?  I'm sure I could write an additional script that it could call, but that just seems silly and it would still echo that.

To be clear, I want terminal to print the returns of the commands, but I'd like the commands themselves to be hidden.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way, but you could use the [appify](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099) script to make your script into an application and move it to your `$HOME/Applications` directory:

```
appify YourShellScript "FunkyApp"
mv FunkyApp.app $HOME/Applications
```

Then in your Applescript:

```
tell application "FunkyApp" to launch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can with "do shell script" in applescript obtain the answer in the script, you can deceive the terminal by sending him a false command with "do script", the bash will post an error without altering the result

```
        try
            tell application "Terminal"
                activate
                set listaffiche to do shell script "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \"Print :IOKitPersonalities:Controller:IOPCIMatch \"  
/System/Library/Extensions
    /AMD5000Controller.kext/Contents/info.plist; /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \"Print 
    :IOKitPersonalities:AMDCedarGraphicsAccelerator\" /System/Library/Extensions
    /AMDRadeonX3000.kext/Contents/info.plist

        "
                do script "" & quoted form of listaffiche --empty and false command 

    whithout echoing how you make the result

            end tell
        end try
```

Comment: And if you suppress activate you have juste one window of terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can with "do shell script" in applescript obtain the answer in the script, you can deceive the terminal by sending him a false command with "do script", the bash will post an error without altering the result and perform the appearance of the result always without echoing with a single window of the Terminal

```
try
    set listaffiche to do shell script "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \"Print :IOKitPersonalities:Controller:IOPCIMatch \"  /System/Library/Extensions/AMD5000Controller.kext/Contents/info.plist; /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \"Print :IOKitPersonalities:AMDCedarGraphicsAccelerator\" /System/Library/Extensions/AMDRadeonX3000.kext/Contents/info.plist "
    tell application "Terminal" to (do script "" & quoted form of listaffiche) launch --empty and false command  whithout echoing how you make the result

end try
```